# Two of the same USB keyboard lag

Tags: keyboard, usb

I have two of the same keyboard, one for work and one for home. They are both USB A keyboards (WASD Keyboards) and I use them with my M1 Macbook Pro running Sonoma 14.0.

They were working great for many years. But some months ago, one of them started lagging a lot. Recently it switched around so it was the other one that started lagging. When I say lagging, I mean that I have to repeat the first key 5-10 times before it registers. Then when the "connection" is made, it works fine for a little while, until the same thing happens again. I've tried to update the firmware of the keyboards, but that has unfortunately not helped.

I've noticed that under Settings > Keyboard > Modifier Keys there is listed "Surface Mobile Mouse" which is a bluetooth mouse I use. My USB keyboard is not listed there at all. Anyway, even if I disconnect the bluetooth mouse, the keyboard issue persists.

If I go through the Change Keyboard Type wizard I have to skip the identification, but then the keyboard appears in the Modifier Keys Select Keyboard dropdown. Then a short while later it disappears again.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the option to test with another keyboard (different product, different vendor)?